# Spring-kafka: Using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with multi concurrency how many messages are fetched per poll?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am running Spring Kafka with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and setting Concurrency to 15 and setting max.poll.records=100.

How many messages are fetched in a single poll? Is it 100 or 1500? If it fetches only 100 will it be fetched from all different partitions or from single partitions?

If it fetches 1500, should I increase my session timeout to avoid rebalance?

Answer (score 0):

Each consumer thread (15) is independent, and will retrieve **up to** 100 records when it calls `poll()`.

The actual number depends on how balanced the data is across the partitions (there must be at least 15 partitions).

As long as you can process 100 records within `max.poll.timeout.ms` (default 5 minutes), there is no need to increase it.

Comment: Yes, we have 15 partitions and records are evenly distributed..Thanks @Gary